# Finding all libraries and header files forming a C++ executable

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

If I have a C++ source file, gcc can give all its dependencies, in a tree structure, using the -H option. But given only the C++ executable, is it possible to find all libraries and header files that went into its compilation and linking?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: to know why a shipped code is outperforming my own in terms of speed and memory when, as far as I know, both use similar libraries and the 'best' coding techniques. (Both codes store boost's sparse matrix [~2 million x 2 million] and perform Lanczos steps. For some reason the shipped code handles memory better although both use boost's mapped_vector_of_vector class and is faster in the multiplications.) So I would have liked to know which faster libraries the shipped code is using, which I felt was the faster route to optimisation rather than detailing what I was doing.

Comment: I guess that it is more a matter of optimization flags (e.g. `-mtune=native -ffast-math -O3`, perhaps even also `-flto`) than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've compiled the executable with debugging symbols, then **yes**, you can use the symbols to get the files.

If you have .pdb files (Visual studio creates them to store sebugging information separately)  you can use all kinds of programs to open them and see the source files and methods.
You can even open it with a text editor and you'll see, among the gibrish, a list of the functions and source files.

If you're using linux (or GNU compilers in general), you can use gdb (again only if you have debug symbols enables in compilation time).
Run gdb on your executable, then run the command: `info sources`

That's an important reason why you should always remove that flag when going into production. You don't want clients to mess around with your sources, functions, and code.

Comment: But most released production-ready executables are without debugging symbols.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that is correct. But it's important to mention that there is a way otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, because that executable might have been build on a machine on which the header files (or the C++ code, or the libraries) are private or even generated. Also, if a static library is linked in, you have no reliable way to find out.

In practice however, on Linux, using `nm` or `objdump` or `ldd` on the executable will *often* (but not always) gives you a good clue about the needed libraries.

Also, some executables are dynamically loading a [plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) e.g. using [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html), so your question might not have any sense (since that plugin is known only at runtime).

Notice also that you might not know if an executable is obtained by compiling some C++ code (you might not be able to tell if it was obtained from C, C++, D, or Ocaml, ... source code, or a mixture of them).

<sup>On Linux, if you build an executable with static linking and stripping, people won't be able to easily guess the source programming language that you have used.</sup>

BTW, on Linux distributions, it is the role of the [package management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system) to deal with such dependencies.

As [answered by Yochai Timmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604105/841108) if the executable contains debug information (e.g. in [DWARF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format) you should be able to get a lot more information.